# How can I return the turbulence sequence with a complexity of O(n)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

pair<int,int> findLongestTurbulence(int arr[], int n){
    pair<int,int> ret  = {0,-1};
    int a = -1;
    for(int start = 0; start < n ; start++ ){
        a = -1;
        for(int end = start+1; end < n ; end ++){
            if(a == -1){
                if(arr[end] > arr[end-1])
                    a=1;
                else if( arr[end] < arr[end-1])
                    a=0;
                else {
                    // no sequence can be generated starting with start 
                    if(end - start > ret.second - ret.first)
                        ret = {start,start};
                    break;      // CHECK FOR NEXT STARTING POINT
                }
            }
            else if(a == 0){
                if(arr[end] > arr[end-1]){
                    a = 1;
                }
                else{
                    // return this start and end point as this sequence cannot be extended more
                    if(end - start > ret.second - ret.first)
                        ret = { start, end-1};
                    break;
                }
            }
            else{
                if(arr[end] < arr[end-1]){
                    a = 0;
                }
                else{
                    // return this start and end point as this sequence cannot be extended more
                    if(end - start > ret.second - ret.first)
                        ret = { start, end-1};
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    return ret;
}
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,8,5,2,6,3,9,7,4,2,3}; // provided sequence 
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    pair<int,int> ans = findLongestTurbulence(arr,n);
    
    for(int i=ans.first;i<ans.second;i++){
        cout<<arr[i]<<", ";
    }
    cout<<arr[ans.second]<<endl;
}
```

My assumption was that it is O(n^2) as it has two nested for loops. The goal this code is trying to achieve is to find a longest turbulence in the
sequence.
‘Turbulence’ is a consecutive sub-sequence where the numbers rise and drop alternately. Every subsequence of a turbulence is also a turbulence.
For example,

• 1 and 8 and 5 are all turbulences because each of them contains only one number.

• 1,8 and 8,5 are both turbulences because 1 rises to 8 in the first sequence and 8 drops to 5 in the second.

• 1,8,5 is a turbulence because 1 rises to 8 and then drops to 5.

• 8,5,2 is not a turbulence because 8 drops twice (first to 5 and then to 2).

• The longest turbulence in the given sequence is 5,2,6,3,9,7 which is also the output.

I think the time complexity of this function is O (n^2) as there are two nested for loops. How would I return the turbulence sequence with a complexity of O(n)?

Comment: so all single digit and all double digit sequences where the two digits are not equal are turbulences?

Comment: Yes, but I need the longest sequence, from the given set which is {1,8,5,2,6,3,9,7,4,2,3}

Comment: is 2,1,2 a turbulence?

Comment: frankly I dont understand why the code is so complicated. You only need a single loop and remember the start point of turbulence, max length and start point of turbulene with max length. Perhaps try to find the longest monotonic increasing subsequence. It is conceptually simpler but then switching to turbulence isnt that hard

Comment: Yes, definitely.

Comment: The greedy approach should do the trick here: Just keep track of the length of the current turbulence and the last turbulence. Let increase, decrease and equality in value be denoted by `+`, `-` and `0`: every time you encounter a`+`or`-`, you can determine,if it continues the current turbulence or ends it at which time you can compare to the longest subsequence so far;similarly `0` always ends a turbulence. Turbulences cannot overlap, since something that ends a turbulence must be `++`, `--`, `+0` or `-0` none of which can be part of a turbulence that extends to the left past the right pos...

Comment: Why do you think you need two loops?  If you have `1 8 5 4 7 3 9 2 6` once you get to the `4` you know the size of the first sequence so you can just continue on and if your next sequence is longer, then toss out that first maximum size and update to the new maximum.

Comment: yeah the key insight is that turbulences can't overlap. because of that you only need one loop.

Comment: It's almost a certainty that the original source of this question is one of the usual suspects -- a clickbait web site that promises to turn anyone into a C++ uberhacker simply by solving their silly coding puzzles. A careful read of all the conditions confirms that this is a trick question. It's only necessary to scan the vector of size `N` once, hence `O(n)` and only noting  consecutive values that are the same. It's trivial to track the longest sequence of values that are not the same as the previous one. It will always be a "turbulence", by definition. Less than ten lines of code. The End.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I admit that your code is too complicated for me. I tried it, but I dont understand it. Anyhow, it can be done with a single loop. To keep it simple I would use two loops (though not nested!). One loop to see if `arr[i] < arr[i+1]` or `arr[i] > arr[i+1]`.

Also too keep it simple you can exclude the case of `arr[i] == arr[i+1]` because when the array has subsequent elements that are equal then you can apply the algorithm on sub arrays. A turbulence never contains elements `arr[i] == arr[i+1]`.

To invent some fance name I call it "polarity" +1 when `arr[i] > arr[i+1]` and -1 when `arr[i] <  arr[i+1]` at even `i`. At odd indices polarity is reversed (ie -1 when `arr[i] > arr[i+1]`).

This is what you'll get:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,8,5,2,6,3,9,7,4,2,3};

    std::vector<int> polarity;
    int flip = 1;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < std::size(arr) -1; ++i){
        if (arr[i] > arr[i+1]) polarity.push_back(1*flip);
        else polarity.push_back(-1*flip);
        flip *= -1;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i< std::size(arr); ++i) {
        std::cout << std::setw(5) << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < std::size(arr)-1; ++i) {
        std::cout << std::setw(5) << polarity[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/8hEnh8j6h):

```
    1     8     5     2     6     3     9     7     4     2     3 
   -1    -1     1     1     1     1     1    -1     1     1
```

I'll leave it to you to find the longest subsequence of equal elements in `polarity`. In this example it is polarity `1` starting at the element with value `5` till `7` (the last entry with polarity 1 corresponds to elements 9 and 7, thats why 7 is included).